# Bizarre mv operation

Tags: command-line, bash, find, mv

The use of a renaming program severely screwed up some of my files. I'm trying to get them back in order.

I have file structure like this:

`./Hello World/some-filename.ext

./Kitty Parade/another.ext

./Third Example/abc.ext

./some-filename.ext2

./another.ext2

./abc.ext2`

The goal is the move the files in current folder (./) back to their original folders.

For example:
`another.ext2` belongs in the `./Kitty Parade/` folder
`some-filename.ext2` belongs in the `./Hello World/` folder
`abc.ex2` belongs in the `./Third Example/` folder`

The rule can be described as this:
If a file exists in current folder (`./`), find a folder than contains a file with the same filename (but with different extension) and move it to that folder. Note: there is no reliable relation between `./myFilename` and that file's `./originalFolderName`.

This happened to over 4,000 files otherwise I'd do it manually. Any possible help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this piece of shell magic:

```
for i in *.*; do
  BASE=$(basename "$i" .ext2)
  LIST=*/"${BASE}".*
  DIR=$(dirname "${LIST}")
  mv -n "$i" "${DIR}"
done
```

Or as an oneliner:

```
for i in *.*; do mv -n "$i" "$(dirname */"$(basename "$i" .ext2)".*)"; done
```

Before:

```
whitequark@forth:~/test$ ls *
test 1.ext2  test 2.ext2  test 3.ext2

f 1:
test 1.ext

f 2:
test 2.ext  test 3.ext
```

After:

```
whitequark@forth:~/test$ ls *
f 1:
test 1.ext  test 1.ext2

f 2:
test 2.ext  test 2.ext2  test 3.ext  test 3.ext2
```

The `-n` switch will protect you from overwriting anything.

Comment: ls `*/"${BASE}".*` heh, nice  Always used find for this.

Comment: `ls` is not necessary: `LIST=*/"${BASE}".*` and `"$(dirname "*/"$(basename "$i" .ext2)".*")"

Comment: @Dennis: thanks, changed. that has remained from previous version of command.